# EditTextPreference not obeying InputType

Tags: android, xml, sharedpreferences, number-formatting, preferences

I want to limit a user to inputing only digits in an EditTextPreference field. I'm using

```
android:inputType="number"
android:digits="0123456789"
```

in my EditTextPreference. I've also tried

```
android:numeric="integer"
```

Neither work in limiting input! A generic keyboard pops up and a user can type anything they want, which obviously breaks an integer-only requirement. Why isn't this working? I'm using a generic PreferenceManager.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change inputType with official library, try to use [Android Support library - preference v7 bugfix](https://github.com/Gericop/Android-Support-Preference-V7-Fix).

As described,

> This library is meant to fix some of the problems found in the official support preference-v7 library

Everything should work with

```
android:inputType="number"
android:digits="0123456789"
```

> Note! Watch out for the correct package name when importing EditTextPreference, it should come from com.takisoft.fix.support.v7.preference